# forward reference with a lookbehind C#?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Is possible use a forward reference with a lookbehind in regex net

I have a string

pathwork 1 pathrelax 6 pathwork 2 pathrelax 7 pathwork 3

```
 (?<=path(\w+)\s(\d)*.*?)path(\w+)(\s\d+)

path$3$4$2
```

I want to obtain

pathwork 1 pathrelax 6 pathwork 21 pathrelax 76 pathwork 32

but i obtain

pathwork 1 pathrelax 61 pathwork 26 pathrelax 72 pathwork 37

I want change

for this command but not work

```
 (?<=path(\2)\s(\d)*.*?)path(\w+)(\s\d+)

    path$3$4$2
```

i read about forward reference http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref2.html#forward

Comment: The .NET syntax looks a bit different in the last example here http://www.regular-expressions.info/refext.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second regex works, you just got the group number wrong:

```
(?<=path(\3)\s(\d)*.*?)path(\w+)(\s\d+)
```

Or you could get rid of that needless group and scale the numbers back:

```
(?<=path\2\s(\d)*.*?)path(\w+)(\s\d+)  // r/w "path$2$3$1"
```

Of course, you don't really have to use forward references.  Just place the lookbehind later in the regex:

```
(path\w+)(?<=\1 +(\d)*.*?\1) +(\d+)  // r/w "$1$3$2"
```

I was going to say it's less confusing this way, but I guess it's just differently confusing.  Forcing regexes to bend over backward is never gonna be pretty.